# Client Side binding of telerik radgrid not updating after databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm trying to bind a radgrid using the client side api.

I issue a call to javascript function DoUpdate(sbiId)

```
function DoUpdate(sbiId) {
    var input = '{"SbiId":"' + sbiId+ '"}';
    var dataSource;

    $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost/Meta.WebService/DataService.svc/GetData",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: input,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            updateGrid(data);
        }
    });
}

function updateGrid(result) {
    var mtv = RadGridSprintBackLogItemDetailsInstance().get_masterTableView();
    mtv.set_dataSource(result);
    mtv.dataBind();
}
```

The ajax call returns seemingly correct JSON data; here is the response content per fiddler:

> {"d":[{"_*type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Bob Hung","ChangedDate":"8/8/2011 3:48:31
>   PM","Description":"","State":"Not Done","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"},{"*_type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Roger Ng","ChangedDate":"8/8/2011 5:12:46
>   PM","Description":"","State":"In Progress","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"},{"_*type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Roger Ng","ChangedDate":"8/8/2011 5:13:39
>   PM","Description":"","State":"In Progress","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"},{"*_type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Roger Ng","ChangedDate":"8/8/2011 5:14:25
>   PM","Description":"Ran into...pointing to the wrong build
>   service","State":"In Progress","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"},{"_*type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Bob Hung","ChangedDate":"8/10/2011 10:59:09
>   AM","Description":"Ran into...pointing to the wrong build
>   service","State":"In Progress","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"},{"*_type":"SBIRevision:#Meta.Scrum","AssignedTo":"Roger
>   Ng","ChangedBy":"Roger Ng","ChangedDate":"8/11/2011 12:04:09
>   PM","Description":"Ran into...pointing to the wrong build
>   service","State":"Done","Title":"MARS Unit
>   Tests","WorkEstimate":"50","WorkRemaining":"50"}]}

Here is how I declare my radgrid on the aspx page

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGridSprintBackLogItemDetails" EnableViewState="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Meta">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableNoRecordsTemplate="true" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">
        <ItemStyle Wrap="false"></ItemStyle>
        <NoRecordsTemplate>
            <div style="margin-left: 5px;">
                Select a Sprint Backlog Item (SBI) from above to view its Revisions</div>
        </NoRecordsTemplate>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChangedDate" HeaderText="Changed Date">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description">
            <ItemStyle Wrap="false"></ItemStyle>
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AssignedTo" HeaderText="Assigned To">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WorkEstimate" HeaderText="Work Estimate">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="WorkRemaining" HeaderText="Work Remaining">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="State" HeaderText="State">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ChangedBy" HeaderText="Changed By">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Oddly enough, after the data is returned and bound, the no records template appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your updateGrid function as follows (use result.d for binding):

```
function updateGrid(result) {
  var mtv = RadGridSprintBackLogItemDetailsInstance().get_masterTableView();
  mtv.set_dataSource(result.d);
  mtv.dataBind(); 
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! A day of frustration because of a .d ! I guess I won't soon forget...

Answer (score 3):

When binding with `set_dataSource()`, you need to pass the actual array of data objects. The jQuery result you are getting contains the data array in a field named `.d`. This is why you need to use `result.d`.

On a side note, did you know that RadGrid can bind to WCF Web Services automatically? Refer to [RadGrid's .NET 3.5 Client-Side DataBinding demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/clientbinding/defaultcs.aspx) for a live example. Service settings are specified right in RadGrid's definition through the markup. RadGrid then automatically connects to the data service, retrieves the result and databinds.

Comment: I think this is the best "answer", because it explains why - then again, most people just want to make it work & move on.... Sample code would make it even better.